# I want columns in same row with no line breaks (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

So my problem is that I have made two columns with Wordpress Gutenberg editor set side by side and I wabt the **Column text 1** to be in left side of the bloc group I have created and the **Column text 2** on the right side.

However the **Column text 2** line breaks to other line when I resize to smaller screen sizes. Is there any solution that the two column texts would stay on same row no matter how small I resize the screen.

Here is simple version of my code with html and css:

https://jsfiddle.net/1ac92xhu/

HTML:

```
    <div class="wp-block-columns">
    <div class="wp-block-column  column-1" style="flex-basis:80%">
    <p>Column text1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wp-block-column column-2 style="flex-basis:20%">
    <p>Column text 2</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .column-1 {
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-basis: 80%;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  }

  .column-2 {

    break-inside: avoid-column;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-right: 1rem;
  }
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70064526/i-want-columns-in-same-row-with-no-line-breaks-flexbox?

Comment: Sorry I accidently posted it twice. I deleted the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add This "word-break: keep-all;"
```

.column-2 {

```
break-inside: avoid-column;
display: flex;
justify-content: right;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-right: 1rem;
```

}

Comment: I am not sure how this would help as this breaks all the letters in word for example to different rows? What i want is the opposite with first column text on left side and the second column text to right side.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @coder1234 You want them to stay in their column as you resize the the window?.

Comment: Yes I want to stay them in their own colums as I resize the window for smaller devices.

Comment: @coder1234 just add a display: flex on wp-block-columns

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can help:

```css
.wp-block-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I would recommend adding a few comments or other helpful bits explaining your code in general; to augment the effectiveness of your answer.